# Spring: как правильно написать условие в контроллере?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Добрый день.
Есть метод в контроллере с условием:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/enter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String enter(@RequestParam(value = "userLogin", required = true) String userLogin,
        @RequestParam(value = "userPassword", required = true) String userPassword, Model model) {

    boolean autRet = userService.aut(userLogin, userPassword);

    if (autRet == true) {
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findUserByLogin(userLogin));
        return "userPage";
    } else {

        return "loginForm";
    }
}
```

Булевый метод для проверки логина и пароля:

```
    public boolean aut(String login, String password) {
    boolean access = false;
    List<User> user = this.findUserByLogin(login);
    for (User userList : user) {
        if (userList != null && userList.getUserPassword() == password) {
            access = true;
        }
    }
    return access;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать условие в контроллере, что бы при  `autRet = true` возвращалась страница `userPage`, а во всех остальных случаях страница `loginForm`?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А что у вас сейчас не работает? Предоставьте лог ошибки или опишите поведение приложения в текущей реализации.

Comment: И почему вы не хотите использовать Spring Security? Функционал, который вы пытаетесь реализовать сами, уже давно отточен по стандартам и предоставляется в виде готовой библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Логин -- поле уникальное. Метод findUserByLogin должен возвращать один объект. Но вместо собственной реализации модели безопасности, лучше посмотреть в сторону spring security